# Google Maps - Heatmap implementation based on?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

There are different kinds of heatmaps:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-build-effective-heat-maps

Just a quick question, is the Google Maps's implementation of heat maps based on Concentration of points (e.g., kernel density) or Distributions of attribute values?

Or is this true?
[Heatmap Tools For Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357721/heatmap-tools-for-web-apps)
"Heat maps are often used in place of a more conventional term: kernel density estimators..."

Sorry I am quite new in this and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

Let me know if after that you still have questions.